# Naming structures on the go

Tags: c

I want to add strings to a structure. 
if the structure is

```
struct{
    char name[100];
}
```

how can I read different strings and then add them to this structure for future use? ideally i want to name each item as name1, name2 etc something like namei. is this possible?

so for instance i am given an input using < file.txt. I divide the text by each line. so when i reach the end of the line, I end the string. Now I want to put this string in a structure and be able to access this string later. Then I reset the string array and do the same for the next line.

Comment: It isn't really feasible.  Referencing the members of the structure requires the offsets to be known at compile time.  Even a structure with a flexible array member (FAM) can have the offsets determined at compile time.  Plus you can't magically create a reference `somestruct.name9` (or `someptr->name8`) at runtime.  Your best bet is probably a FAM in the structure — an array whose size can be varied at runtime.  Instead of `name1`, you just use `1` (or perhaps `0`).

Comment: @jonathan my task is to read a file from stdin and divide it into lines. then for each line i have to check if certain words appear in the line and then give each line a score based on how often the given words occur. and print this out. then i have to sort the lines using the scores and print the lines with the highest scores. i thought of using arrays but ran into the problem you mentioned.

Comment: It screams 'use arrays' to me.  Anything else is not very sensible.

Comment: using struct arrays?

Comment: No. You won't learn anything if I do your homework for you. If you make an honest attempt and run into problems, we'll help. But no, we don't do your homework. Please review how to create an MCVE ([MCVE]) before adding to this question or creating a new one.  I suggest deleting this, at least for long enough to edit in your decent attempt and a description of the problems you're facing. For line reading, use [`fgets()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/fgets.html) or perhaps POSIX 
[`getline()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/getline.html)

Comment: Maybe this little emphasis will help you to get Jonathans very good advice: Use **only** an array (of pointers to malloced spaces with char), forget about struct. If you cannot predict a suitable maximum number of lines... then you are in deeper waters, with data constructs like dynamic linked lists.

Comment: If Jonathans and my comments are unclear to you (which would be understandable), then I recommend finding a tutorial a few steps earlier in your learning progress and (re-) do it thoroughly.

Comment: Yes they are a little unclear but i will try to figure out what you guys mean and try to implement it. Thanks for your help

Comment: I think you have two choices: an array of pointers (realloc()'d to accommodate additional lines) that points to malloc()'d memory that holds the lines (disadvantage is it's comparatively slow--realloc() may result in memory copies; the advantage is that it's simple to implement), or create a struct that contains a pointer to the line of input and a next pointer, and put them together into a linked list.  This is a little more work to implement, uses a bit more memory, but is faster to execute.  Given that you don't need random access to the lines, linked list is probably better.